# Can I use Hortonworks Sandbox on Mac M1?

Tags: hadoop, virtualbox, hortonworks-sandbox

I have installed Virtualbox developer preview on my Mac M1 and am trying to run Hortonworks Sandbox on it. However, the application keeps closing when I click 'Start' and I cannot find any information on my that is happening. The error message that showed up was 'You must specify a machine to start, using the command line.' When I looked up this error, everyone says to use an older version of Virtualbox but there is no older version that is compatible with Mac M1. Can someone tell me how I can fix this problem and run sandbox on my system?

Answer (score 1):

Hortonworks doesn't exist as a company anymore, and the sandbox hasn't been updated since before M1 Macs were even available, so unless you want to run x86 VM in VirtualBox (or Docker image with Qemu), no, it's not possible.

Latest Hadoop 3 already supports ARM processors, and you can use Homebrew to install it. The Sandbox uses old Hadoop 2.7.3, last I checked.