# how to deploy hortonworks sandbox on mac0s M1

Tags: hadoop, vmware, hortonworks-sandbox

i have been trying to deploy hortonworks on my mac M1 but nothing seems to work. i have tried all the possible guides provided by Cloudera[Deploying Hortonworks Sandbox on VirtualBox, Deploying Hortonworks Sandbox on VMWare, Deploying Hortonworks Sandbox on Docker.

i tried vmware but every time try to run hortonworks i'll get an error that says :"This virtual machine cannot be powered on because it requires the X86 machine architecture, which is incompatible with this Arm machine architecture host" as show on this screenshot

[image].

i tried visualbox and i'll get an error : "visualbox quite unexpectedly". not running

i tried docker, error as well which i cannot remember but wasnt working, i could not access the localhost. got errors.

i tried installing hadoop directly to my system but got arrors that  says: "log4j not initiated properly" and so could not access localhost and nodes did not start properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use Hortonworks Sandbox on Mac M1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74564541/can-i-use-hortonworks-sandbox-on-mac-m1)

Comment: _tried installing hadoop directly to my system but got arrors that says: "log4j not initiated properly"_ - Then initialize it? Or use Docker instead of a VM / your host? Also, you can run Mapreduce or Spark *without Hadoop*.