# how to access hortonworks sandbox on the browser from docker on macos m1

Tags: docker, hadoop, sandbox, hortonworks-sandbox

i have successfully deployed hortonworks sandbox on docker on my macos m1, the containers and images are displayed on the docker but i cannot seems to access hortonworks on my local browser.

i have attached the screenshoot of the hortonworks containers and images deployed on docker below

please, i need assistant on this, guys.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOVsN.png)

i added the below code to the /etc/hosts file :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost   sandbox.hortonworks.com
```

but cannot access the container on the browser. i have tried possibly information i could find online .

Answer (score 0):

`docker ps` says both containers are not running, therefore no ports will be accessible (also the `PORTS` column is empty).

137 exit code means you need to give more memory to Docker Desktop since the sandbox will try to start HDFS, YARN, Hive, Ambari, etc, etc all in one container rather than, more appropriately in separate containers with Docker Compose...

Also, last I checked, the Sandbox has not been supported or maintained for over 5 years, [as mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76467644/how-to-deploy-hortonworks-sandbox-on-mac0s-m1). You can run Hadoop itself using other, more updated images.

Comment: thanks @OneCricketeer. i actually took the screenshoot when the containers were not running. however, i have increased the docker memory to 8Gg and below is a screenshoot of the containers when running. i cannot seems to access it via local browser. please any further information on what i should do. thank you. Screenshot 2023-06-21 at 10.51.11 PM

Comment: Screenshots cannot go in comments. As mentioned, the ports column tells you want to connect to